# Writing a nested loop in python

Tags: python, loops, nested, nested-loops

I'm a Python beginner struggling to write code that uses the list `myList = [['A','B','C'],[4,5,​6],[7,8,9]]` and generates the output below:

Input:

```
myList = [['A','B','C'],[4,5,​6],[7,8,9]]
```

Expected output: (by line)

```
-A-B-C-
-4-5-6-
-7-8-9-
```

I've tried a few different things but am not sure how to approach the confluence of strings and integers in the same list.

I can get:

```
>>> for i in range (0,myList_len):
...     print ("-".join(myList[i]))
... 
A-B-C
```

But I can't get this to work for the numbers. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You want help or the problem solved? If it's help, then start by reading whats the error you're getting for number. Then try to fix that. Aaaaaand, that's it (for this case).

Comment: Where did `myList_len` come from? You can iterate the list directly: `for i in myList:`.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map` to convert from `int` to `str`

```
for l1 in myList:
   print '-' + '-'.join(map(str, l1)) + '-'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to join numbers, you get the following error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

This is because `str.join()` only works with `str` items in the iterable, but you pass it `int` objects instead.

So in order to properly join them, you need to convert them to strings first. You can either do that by calling `str` on every item using `map`, or by using a list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [4, 5, 6]
>>> '-'.join(map(str, lst))
'4-5-6'
>>> '-'.join([str(x) for x in lst])
'4-5-6'
```

Answer (score 0):

The "join" operator expects a list of strings, so you have to turn your numbers to strings first, using the "str" operator that turns anything into a string.

```
for l in myList:
   print '-' + '-'.join([str(x) for x in l]) + '-'
```

Comment: Correct. I fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

**join** works on strings, not numbers.  You need to convert:

```
print ("-".join(str(num) for num in myList[i]))
```

Now, just add the hyphens at start and finish, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for sublist in myList:
    print("-".join(map(str, sublist)))
```

The output is:

```
A-B-C
4-5-6
7-8-9
```

If you want leading and trailing hyphens as well, use:

```
for sublist in myList:
    print("-" + "-".join(map(str, sublist)) + "-")
```

The output is:

```
-A-B-C-
-4-5-6-
-7-8-9-
```

The `for` loop iterates over the sublists.  The `map(str, sublist)` call applies `str` to each element of the sublist, converting it to a string.  Without this, your non-string entries (i.e., numbers) were causing errors when passed to `join`.